# Bring Minimized Browser Window Forward (Focus)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to bring forward a minimized popup browser window?

I have a webpage that launches a music player in a separate window that is activated by a "Listen Now" button. I would like the ability to bring that window up if a user clicks on the Listen Now button again.

So for example, here would be the ideal steps:

1. User visits PAGE 1, clicks "Listen Now"
2. Music player window pops up in PAGE 2
3. User goes about their day and either buries or minimizes the player window
4. User goes back to PAGE 1 and clicks "Listen Now"
5. Minimized PAGE 2 pops up.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Jay

Comment: I hope not, that would be really intrusive for something to keep popping up after I minimize it.

Comment: You're not allowed to do this in JavaScript. Maybe you can do this with a browser extension but that is platform dependent.

Comment: Peter, it would be initiated by user, not just randomly pop up :)

Comment: is there no win32 api that does that? i also interested about it

Comment: There is a way to do it as I've seen the behavior on websites, but no one here seemed to know how it was done. We changed our behavior so didn't need the feature. Good luck.